# Can I get cashback for buying gift cards on Amazon?

Tags: credit-card, savings, credit, visa

I have an Amazon Prime Rewards Visa Signature Card that gets me 5% cashback on purchases made through Amazon. 
Is it possible to reap that reward on gift card purchases?

Comment: Yes, and the thinking is if you ever give checks or cash to friends or family as gifts, and if you know they use amazon, now you can send them amazon gift cards instead and earn 5% cash back on your gifts to friends and family.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, and Amazon [advertises this feature](https://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?docId=1000579861).

Comment: That specifically refers to Amazon gift card purchases. I'm curious about all gift card purchases. For example, they sell Southwest Airlines gift cards, fulfilled through Prime.

Comment: The same rules apply to all purchases made on Amazon.com

Comment: How did you find that?? It's dated 2010

Comment: @Azor-Ahai I can't speak for Nathan but if you google "amazon gift card cash back" it's the first result.

Comment: :O wasn't 2010 when dinosaurs roamed the earth or something?

Comment: The terms in that advertisement say "**on or before October 31st, 2010.**"